# NVIDIA Driver troubles on GeForce2 Go at 1600x1200

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, hardware-acceleration

My system (Dell Inspiron 8100) uses Nvidia NV11 GeForce2 Go at 1600x1200.  All is working, save I cannot get any hardware acceleration, making video playback and animation unbearably slow and jerky.  In "Additional Drivers" I show TWO instances of NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU binary.  Neither is "activated" and when I try to activate I get "SystemError: E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages"

I have no clue what package might have been "held" as as far as I know I never refused to allow any upgrades.  I would like to simply remove BOTH instances of the binary, but nothing I have tried works.

Doing an lshw scan for nvidia hardware reports the driver=nouveau.

I tried to do the update to the nvidia-current, and remove nouveau, but that failed, leaving me running in 800x600 degraded mode.  The Nvidia-Settings app reported no Nvidia driver installed after the update.  I tried several attempts to force it, by editing xorg.confg and other hacks with no luck.

I think my problems stem from the broken binary drivers inhabiting the additional drivers app, and if I can get them out, the nvidia-current might install correctly.  But despite many attempts, I am just stuck.

Help Please?  I am unable to proceed at this point, having exhausted all my own expertise.  The system works fairly well, save the lack of acceleration.  I just need to get over that little bump and I would be one happy camper.  Any clue would be most appreciated.

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: What do the errors say? Run: sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: What errors?  I listed the systemerror reported above.  If apt-get upgrade would have fixed anything I wouldn't be here.  Done that.  It downloads nvidia-current and seems to install, but as I described it fails and throws me into degraded mode.  I have no clue why, other than the oddity of two binaries.

Comment: Really you have broken packages and apt-get doesn't show anything?

Comment: Not that I can see.  Maybe I'm missing something, but it just seems to do it's thing without mentioning any issues with the duplicated drivers, or anything obviously connected to them.

Comment: @Nathan: you listed errors from the GUI package manager, never mentioned running the commandlines that were suggested, and now you're getting an attitude; this isn't a good way to get help from volunteers.  But if it helps, I've always gotten a failure trying to install the newer version driver of the two.

Comment: Hmm.  I am not following.  I thought my description of the problem was clear and concise.  I was asked about errors, and there weren't any save those I reported.  So because I said so, I now have an attitude.  Amazing!

Comment: Nathan, run the apt-get commands in terminal, then include the output in your question. Broken pacakges will be listed in that, not the GUI.

Comment: Here is the output of the two commands: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11336636/output.txt  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11336636/output2.txt

Comment: No joy but I was poking around the nvidia web site and they say the last official driver to support my card is the -96.  So I tried running apt-get install nvidia-96.  It said: The Following Packages have unmet dependencies:  nvidia-96 : depends xorg-video-abi-10 but it is not installable. E: Unable to correct you have held broken packages.  I tried installing -96 directly from the nvidia site using the procedure they gave, but it rendered the system non-booting.  So I restored my Clonezilla image and am back to square one.

Comment: Have you searched Launchpad for bugs? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-173/+bug/948053

Comment: Solution found!  The business of the bogus "Additional Drivers" entries was a red herring.  Turns out the problem was color depth.  This old and wimpy machine simply cannot handle the default color depth that 12.04 assigns.  Installing a basic xorg.conf setting color depth to 16, down from the default of 32, made a huge, huge difference.  There is still room for improvement, but I do not expect miracles from such very old hardware.  It now plays Youtube videos, in the browser window just fine.  Of course full-screen is too much, but that is to be expected.  I still have bogus prop drivers tho

Comment: @Nathan : Please post your solution as an answer and accept it to close this question! Good catch. Note that VDPAU/"hardware acceleration" is not available on that video card. I had that exact same 1600x1200 laptop until about a year ago - almost 9 years.

Answer (score 1):

The OP [found a solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143751/nvidia-driver-troubles-on-geforce2-go-at-1600x1200#comment172961_143751). Reformatted excerpt:

> The business of the bogus "Additional Drivers" entries was a red
>   herring. Turns out the problem was color depth. This old and wimpy
>   machine simply cannot handle the default color depth that 12.04
>   assigns.
>
> Installing a basic `xorg.conf` setting color depth to 16, down from
>   the default of 32, made a huge, huge difference.
>
> There is still room for improvement, but I do not expect miracles from
>   such very old hardware. It now plays Youtube videos, in the browser
>   window just fine. Of course full-screen is too much, but that is to be
>   expected.